# Webform message appeas when hitting the back button on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When the user or the password is typed wrong, I show a message box similar with this :

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('User or password typed wrong');</script>", false)`;

When i log in with correct user and password and I hit the back button on the explorer, the previous page with same error popup dialog window is there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The back button will load from local browser cache the previously rendered page.

You can either disable back button using javascript on the client side or browser caching using C#.

With javascript:

```
function DisableBack() {
    window.history.forward()
}
DisableBack();
window.onload = DisableBack;
window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) DisableBack() }
window.onunload = function() { void (0) }
```

Or on the following page:

```
this.history.forward(-1);
```

With C#:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```